# How to make division in Python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Consider below is my data frame and I want to populate Percentage column by dividing individual marks with Total to get the percentage.

```
    Name  Marks
0  Total    100
1  Name1     45
2  Name2     65
3  name3     93
4  name4     89
```

I have written the code like this

```
for i in range(0,5):
        pcnt=(df['Marks'][i])/(df['Marks'][0])
        df['Percentage']=pcnt*100
```

But the percentage column just produce 0 for all rows. The above code is just for an example but my actual data produce some error like the below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/USER/.PyCharmCE2017.2/config/scratches/scratch.py", line 24, in <module>
    share=df2['W/E 17/11/2013'][i]/df2['W/E 17/11/2013'][0]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 623, in __getitem__
    result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2560, in get_value
    tz=getattr(series.dtype, 'tz', None))
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 83, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 91, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 139, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 811, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 817, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
KeyError: 74L
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you can use [`Series.div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.div.html) by first row selected by  [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and then multiple by [`mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mul.html):

```
s = df['Marks'].div(df.loc[0, 'Marks']).mul(100)
print (s)
0    100.0
1     45.0
2     65.0
3     93.0
4     89.0
Name: Marks, dtype: float64
```

If real data have no index `0` in first row, is use general solution - select by position by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) with [`get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) for position of column `Marks`:

```
print (df.iloc[0, df.columns.get_loc('Marks')])
100

s = df['Marks'].div(df.iloc[0, df.columns.get_loc('Marks')]).mul(100)
```

Comment: Works perfect. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it without the loop is this:

```
df['Percentage'] = (df['Marks'] / df.loc[0, 'Marks']) * 100:

>>> df
    Name  Marks  Percentage
0  Total    100       100.0
1  Name1     45        45.0
2  Name2     65        65.0
3  name3     93        93.0
4  name4     89        89.0
```

**Problem with your attempt**

It is possible to assign values by loop, as you were trying, but *typically not recommended*. In any case, the reason your particular loop doesn't work is this:

Consider your original `df`:

```
>>> df
    Name  Marks
0  Total    100
1  Name1     45
2  Name2     65
3  name3     93
4  name4     89
```

The last step of your loop assigns `df['Percentage']` to a single float value. If you do this, that entire column gets assigned the same value:

```
df['Percentage'] = 123.0
>>> df
    Name  Marks  Percentage
0  Total    100       123.0
1  Name1     45       123.0
2  Name2     65       123.0
3  name3     93       123.0
4  name4     89       123.0
```

So at each iteration of your loop, you're reassigning the entire column to the last calculated `pcnt`.

If you wanted to correct this, you could assign `df['percentage']` only at the desired index:

```
for i in range(0,5):
    pcnt=(df['Marks'][i])/(df['Marks'][0])
    df.loc[i, 'Percentage']=pcnt*100
```

One other problem you have is that you're using [chain indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#why-does-assignment-fail-when-using-chained-indexing), which is not ideal for a number of reasons (e.g. `df['Marks'][i]`), and will undoubtedly lead you to some warning messages at some point. Better to use the `.loc` method of `pandas`:

```
for i in range(0,5):
    pcnt=(df.loc[i, 'Marks'])/(df.loc[0, 'Marks'])
    df.loc[i, 'Percentage']=pcnt*100
```

But all that is just to show you the problem. When possible, it's better to use vectorized approaches rather than loops when using pandas, it's faster, and once you get the hang of it, it's usually easier to write.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Understood the logic